# How to resolve "Too many open files" problems with netty

Tags: netty

[too many open files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDycx.jpg)

When I using netty based http server in our product env. I find after working for some days the server will encount a very serious error "Too many open files" and this cannot recover automaticly after shut down the incoming requests ,this exception  was thrown out without stopping,I must restart the server manually.

I added a handler to the acceptor thead as below:

```
    serverBootstrap.channelFactory(new ChannelFactory<ServerChannel>() {
            @Override
            public ServerChannel newChannel() {

                NioServerSocketChannel nioServerSocketChannel = new NioServerSocketChannel();
                nioServerSocketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

                        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                        System.out.println("Thread " + name +" add handler! ");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {

                        cause.printStackTrace();
                        LOG.error("Error occurs!",cause);

                    }
                });

                return nioServerSocketChannel;
            }
        });
```

I can catch this exception here but don't know how to process it

if I can refuse this connection or given a friendly response?

how to recover from this problem?

many thanks!

Comment: You are leaking sockets, which can only mean you aren't closing them when done. Don't post pictures of text here, let alone links to pictures of text. Post the text.